# ASP.NET - Imitating a desktop app that copies files to a temp location before upload - possible strategies

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload

We have a desktop app that allows users to fill in a questionnaire.  For certain question types, users can upload files.  The desktop app performs the following logic:

- copies the file to a temp location
- reads the bytes from the copy and caches in memory
- uploads all cached bytes when the questionnaire is submitted

It doesn't take more than five seconds of googling to see that client-side file access from a web app is a security hole.  I gather it's possible if you cripple your security settings but there is no way our IT dept will allow that :).

The requirement that the desktop app logic is designed to fulfil is to not keep the user waiting during the process of filling out indovidual questions.  The only wait they experience is at the very end when they hit the "Submit" button.  At this point, all questions and files are submitted.

However, after googling, I now think that I will not be able to do offer this in the web version.

So my actual question is:  Is there a way to fulfil the requirement of no file transfer until the end of the questionnaire proccess?  Can you perhaps create a set of posted files from a set of cached file names?  What I need is a way to do a multiple file upload from a set of cached file paths.

But I'm not sure this will be good enough without a copy having been created of the files first....e.g. what happens if the user deletes the file after assigning it to a question but before they submit the questionnaire?

I have looked through all the questions listed as similar to mine but not seen anything that I think I can use.  Any tips will be very gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You don't want to keep people waiting, so just store the paths of the files and upload them at the end. Check they exist when the submit button is hit, then upload them one after the other. You could even use the Ajax asynchronous file uploader so they can upload files while continuing to work on the questionnaire. Are you worried that uploading actual files is a security hole? As long as you only permit uploads of the type you want (such as .pdf) then you should not have any issues... unless I am missing something?

Comment: SLC, that was more than a comment. It's a valid answer. Why didn't you psot it as an answer?

Comment: @SLC - Hi, yes this did occur to me and was what I meant when I asked if I could create a set of HttpPostedFiles from cached filenames.  However, I followed this with the concern that this does not guard against the file being moved or deleted before the upload button is pressed.  Ideally, I need no delay and some assurance that the file to transfer will be there (as this is what the desktop version offers).

Comment: @SLC - " just store the paths of the files and upload them at the end" - After a bit of investigation - As far as I can tell, I can only get access to the file via the HttpPostedFile instance provided by the FileUpload.  So, unless I cache the whole object in session state at the time the user clicks "OK", I'm not sure how I will access the files later when they click the Submit button?  Or is there another way?  What you said about the Ajax asynchronous file uploader is something I will try (at the same time as I am trying the IFrame suggestions from the other guys).

Comment: Any chance you could use Silverlight? It might help simplify some of this logic for you; it should be faster, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform the upload in the background using an iframe. This would alow the user to continue filling in the questionaire as they moved through the process.

You'd have to design your questionaire forms using Ajax correctly though so as not to transition pages whilst the upload(s) were happening.

You'd also have to put a progress bar or something on the final page to ensure all files were uploaded before they closed the browser.

Comment: We put this in place yesterday.  We will probably have a play with the Ajax control kit uploader comtrol as well but just not had a chance yet.  Thanks all fo rthe help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for multi-file uploads. Have a look at [this article](http://www.codetoad.com/ASP.NET_multiplefileupload.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with Lee Hesselden. The possible solution is to use background uploading through invisible iframe.
Recently we have implemented multiple file uploader for ASP.NET this way. Moreover, currently it is available for free. See [demo page](http://liveui.net/demo-bugtracker/Tasks/15?grid=demo-bugtracker%2fTasks%3fsortdir%3dAscending%26start%3d0)